# Why does my WIFI turn off randomly?

Tags: wi-fi

I am using a government ZTE Qlink phone and the WIFI randomly turns itself off. I have too many contacts to perform a factory reset! I need help figuring it out!

Comment: Does it lose connection? Or the adapter actually turns off?

Answer (score 2):

Practically all mobile phones are using the [Google Contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.contact) app to manage your contacts. They create a backup of your contacts to the Google, and continuously synchronizing with it. This is why you can see the same contacts on all your Android devices (if you have multiple).

If not this is the case on your phone, you need only to install the Google Contacts app.

If you don't want to share your contacts with the Google, there are also many third-party apps to save them to other cloud services, or to your own machine. You can find them quickly with Google searches :-)

Having your contacts saved with an app, your contact list will survive a factory reset. Note, there is a high chance, that it won't fix your problem. In my experience, such sudden wifi disconnections root probably in the bad hardware/driver, or in some overloading of your device by the recently hugely grown apps. If you have no better option, it surely worths a try.

Answer (score 1):

Which phone are you using? Go to `Settings` -> `About Phone` and check for system updates. If an update is available, do it right away.

If the problem still persists, then you should try to reset your phone.

If you are worried about losing your contacts, then you don't need to worry. On an Android device, your contacts are already been synced with google service. You can even check your contacts on the https://contacts.google.com .

Many other free contact backup apps are also available on the Internet. So you can backup your contacts/sms/call_logs and everything else to external card and then restore them any time.